# Asking for correct ways to do "power counting" for gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, dimensional-analysis, yang-mills

I am looking into Weinberg "Quantum Theory of Fields" Volume 1 Ch. 12-1.

There, he discusses the general rules of power counting.

He defines the UV asymptotics of the propagator $\Delta_f$ for a field labeld by "f" as
\begin{equation}
\Delta_f(k) \simeq k^{-2+2s_f} \text{ as } k \to \infty.
\end{equation}
so that $s_f = 0, 1/2, 1$ for scalar fields / Dirac fields / massive vector fields respectively. For massless vector fields, $s_f=0$ of course.

So, let us consider a Feynman diagram with

1. $I$ number of internal lines corresponding to the field "$f$"
2. $N$ number of vertices corresponding to an interaction term in the Lagrangian with $d$ number of derivatives

Then, the degree of divergence $D$ for the diagram is
\begin{equation}
D=I(2s_f-2)+ dN + 4(I-N+1)
\end{equation}
where the last term $4(I-N+1)$ comes from the momentum space integration under the constraint of momentum conservation.

However, I am very much confused about how we can apply these rules to non-Abelian gauge theories. More precisely:
\begin{equation}
\text{ Can we just naively count the number of "ordinary" derivatives in the Lagrangian and plug them into the above formulas?}
\end{equation}

Moreover,
\begin{equation}
\text{ if we are to fix a gauge, each gauge fixing yields an extra term in the propagator with its own singularty in the UV limit}
\end{equation}
so that power counting seems affected by choice of gauge.

Could anyone please provide some clarification?

P.S. I deleted the duplicate post....Is it okay now, QMechanics?